# Does Captain Kirk drink decaf?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In many episodes of Star Trek TOS, Kirk is seen either drinking coffee or being served coffee by one of his yeomen. With all that is known about Kirk in Memory Alpha and other canonical sources, it seems strange to me that I do not know what kind of coffee he drinks. After all, Captain Picard is known to specifically drink Earl Grey tea. Does Kirk have a known caffeine preference? Is it possible that it depends on which yeoman is serving him? This would make some sense, as his behavior on the bridge can range from the very animated to the slightly sleepy.

Comment: One thing's for certain - it wasn't [raktajino](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Raktajino).

Comment: I don't think there was ever a canon mention of decaf and Captain Kirk in the same sentence.  If anything Kirk doesn't pussy-foot around with decaf, he's probably expresso or nothing.

Comment: I can't make this an answer, since there is little evidence... but I think he liked his coffee at least 80 proof.

Comment: To be honest, this question made me smile. :) I immediately had two cameos/jokes in my mind: old and fat/slow Kirk in The Simpsons and the keyed up Kirk from Family Guy... there could really be some connection to the coffee (even if not intentional).

Comment: “Captain Picard is known to specifically drink Earl Grey tea.” Hot. With nothing in it.

Comment: Honestly...it's possible ALL coffee that is replicated in the Star Trek universe is decaf - if Synthehol can't make you drunk, why should Shythecoffee give you a buzz?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the Trek novel [Enterprise: The First Adventure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0091OUXAS) a bleary-eyed Kirk snaps at Yeoman Rand before heading for the synthesizer to get the day's first coffee.  The coffee tasted awful but Kirk drank it anyway and then woke up sufficiently to realize he'd been rude to Rand and apologized.  No one drinks bad coffee first thing in the morning unless it has caffeine in it, so I'd say that Kirk drinks caffeinated coffee.

Comment: I disagree. No one lets more than 4 minutes pass between being rude to Rand and apologizing.