# What is the ratio of time dilation in "Wink of an Eye"

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

After swatting a fly on my desk today I randomly recalled the *Star Trek: The Original Series* episode "Wink of an Eye", in which the Scalosians are a race of hyper-accelerated beings that eventually bring Kirk into their own time frame once he drinks his coffee (of which we have reached a conclusion on its [caffeinated nature](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26542/does-captain-kirk-drink-decaf)).

Though everyone appears to be frozen, they are actually moving at a much slower pace than Kirk and the Scalosians. What I am wondering is, what is the exact ratio of time dilation that is occurring here? I do not remember if it was mentioned in the episode or not. Assuming it was not, is it possible to determine by calculating the speed of phaser fire when Kirk fires at Deela?

Assuming it's 1000:1, this would mean that for every minute of passing time in the "normal" time line, Kirk would have experienced over 16 hours of time. Once we have discovered the ratio, how long is Captain Kirk actually in his hyper-accelerated state when compared to the flow of normal time?

Comment: You might as well be asking about _Honey, I Shrunk The Kids_; the science is just as bad.

Comment: Indeed. I have rewatched this episode since posting my question and you are correct. I did not recall it being so inconsistent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ratio was never stated in the episode.  Pitching human voices up until they sound like the whine of insect wings gives a time compression multiple of around 10.  But that isn't really fast enough to explain effects seen in the episode, such as unaccelerated people looking like statues and accelerated humans moving so fast as to be invisible to the unaccelerated.  The time compression effect was depicted inconsistently, not only in the degree of slowdown/speedup but also in ignoring side-effects that would have been deadly to the Scolosians and to the Enterprise crew.  So I don't think there is a single reliable answer to this question.

Comment: You are exactly correct. This episode made a lot more sense in my memory than it did after a rewatch. I appreciate the attempt to answer the question, however! +1