# What Star Trek TOS episode featured lifeforms on the Enterprise living much slower/faster than the crew?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, episode-identification

There was an episode with a different lifeform living at a slower/faster speed aboard the Enterprise? Would have been in a late 60s episode.

Comment: I'm so surprised this isn't a duplicate. Good question!

Comment: Related question - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/27266/54605

Answer (score 20):

The episode is *Wink of an eye*.  This was episode 11 in Season 3.  The description from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wink_of_an_Eye),

> "Wink of an Eye" is a third season episode of the original science fiction television series, Star Trek, first broadcast on November 29, 1968, and repeated on June 24, 1969. It is episode #66, production #68, and was written by Arthur Heinemann, based on a story by Gene L. Coon (under the pen name Lee Cronin), and directed by Jud Taylor.
>
> In this episode, normally invisible time-accelerated aliens take over the Enterprise and attempt to abduct the crew for use as "genetic stock".

Comment: Whoa... this is actually *really* interesting premise for a story. Any other stories built around this general idea in other fiction? In particular the idea of time acceleration/deceleration (and not just suspended-slumber/awakening).

Comment: @zxq9 If you like Sci-Fi enough to be on this site, you owe it to yourself to watch all of TOS. It's literally Golden Age Sci-Fi put onto TV. I believe there was a Physics.SE question about whether it is even possible to move so fast that you would not be seen and the general consensus was "No", since you'd have to move fast enough to become incandescent (so you'd be seen one way or the other). So "harder" Sci-Fi writers might shy away from the premise based on its real-world impossibility.

Comment: @ToddWilcox When I was a kid my brother and I watched rather a lot of it, but that was 30 years ago and I was quite young. Now that I'm older... who has the time to actually watch TV?!? (>.<) If I strike it rich this will be somewhere near the top of my todo list in terms of media. As for hard sci-fi... the invisibility idea is less interesting than maybe a species that could turn into a wrapped dimension, and perhaps observe a different scale or direction of their arrow of time -- and thus selectively interact with us (?). I'm really thinking storytelling, not science in this regard. Tricky.

Comment: @zxq9: One very interesting story that explores a similar theme is the short story "The River of Time" in the collection of the same name by David Brin.